# Jquery val() number not correct?

Tags: jquery, frontend

I am building a simple if statement, using Jquery to change the colour of a P element if the input's value is over 6. However it changes when the input value is over 2?

```
$("#input_5_11").keyup(function() {     
  if ($('#input_5_11').val() > 6) {
    $("p").css("color", "red")
  }
});
```

Comment: your code looks good and should work if value is over 6. Pls share your html code

Comment: sharing your HTML code would really help us.

Comment: Can you modify the question to include a **[mcve]**?  As it stand it should just work so I can't reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 6):

You're comparing a string and an int. Use `parseInt()` to coerce the `val()` to an integer:

```
$("#input_5_11").keyup(function() {     
  if ((parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0) > 6) {
    $("p").css("color", "red")
  }
});
```

Also note the use of `|| 0` to coerce a `NaN` result to `0` in order not to break the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function of javascript as you are currently comparing with string.

```js
$("#input_5_11").keyup(function() {     
  if (Number($(this).val()) > 6) {
      $("p").css("color", "red").text('now I am Red');
  }
  else{
     $("p").css("color", "green").text('back to green');
  }
});
```

```css
p{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_5_11" value="4"/>
<p>I am green initially</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#input_5_11").keyup(function() {     
      if (+($(this).val()) > 6) {
        $("p").css("color", "red")
      }
  });
```

Just convert/parse the string value of the input to a number by parsing it to an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: actually you're not resetting the `p` color to the default one. Also, only numbers will cause the color to change, non-numeric characters will reset the color to the default

```js
$("#input_5_11").keyup(function() {  
        var v = parseInt($(this).val());
        v = (!isNaN(v)) ? v:0;
        if (v > 6) {
            $("p").css("color", "red")
        } else {
            $("p").css("color", "black"); // or any default color
        }     
});
```

```html
            
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="input_5_11" />
    <p>I am p tag</p>
```